# \twocolumn undefined control sequence }]

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, subfloats, two-column

I am trying to add a figure (a `center` environment) two a `\twocolumn` command. I tried this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{%
\begin{center}
\captiontype{figure}
\subfloat[]
  {
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} }
  }
\subfloat[]
  {
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} }
  }
\caption{Our algorithms.}
\end{center}
}] %end twocolumn

\end{document}
```

but I get "undefined control sequence }]". Any suggestions?

Comment: The undefined control sequence is `\captiontype`. What precisely do you want to do?

Comment: Bah, sorry. I didn't realize there was a different output tab. Is there a way to delete this question? It surely is not useful for others.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in posting an object across two columns in the `\twocolumn` macro, it should be void of any floats. Here's an option by setting the contents of the two-column spread without resorting to `\subfloat`. Accurate referencing capability can be incorporated, if needed.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn]{article}
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
%\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
\usepackage{caption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/caption
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum

\begin{document}

\twocolumn[{%
\hfill%
\parbox{.4\textwidth}{\centering%
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} } \\[\abovecaptionskip]
  \small (a)
}%
\hfill%
\parbox{.4\textwidth}{\centering%
  \fbox{\rule{0pt}{1in} Some text \rule{1in}{0pt} } \\[\abovecaptionskip]
  \small (b)
}%
\hspace*{\fill}
\captionof{figure}{Our algorithms.}
%\end{center}
}] %end twocolumn

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

The horizontal alignment is performed using `\hfill`, while the contents of the "subfloats" are set inside a `\parbox`. This allows for using a paragraph break (via `\\[\abovecaptionskip]`).

The [`caption` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) provides the caption as needed without being inside a floating environment, while [`lipsum`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum) generates some dummy text.

There are other ways of having a single-column figure (float) in a two-column document (via `figure*`). Although the placement of such floats might be not what the users wants.

Comment: What is wrong with having floats inside the \twocolumn?

Comment: @DavidDoria: There's nothing wrong, but if you want a single-column float in the `\twocolumn` document, the *placement* is not always are requested. See [Wide figures in two-column documents](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=widefigs).